# copy array of holiday weeks into a new calendar

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Updated code, new trouble below.

I am evolving this script to copy complete holiday weeks into a new calendar.

It works nice with any of the array members now, when no other events are existing in the destination calendar:

```
 if ( eventToCheck.length == 0 ) {
            copyHoliday = true;
          }
```

[image]

but when there are existing other events nothing happens:

```
for (var j = 0;  eventToCheck.length > 0; j++) {
  if ( eventToCheck[j].getTitle() !== holidayArray[0][1] ) {
    copyHoliday = true;
  }
```

[image]
[image]

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTitle' of undefined: I thought where eventToCheck is the array of all existing events, eventToCheck[j] should be the jth event and should therefore have a title. Is this wrong?

Complete Code:

```
 function copy5yHoliday() {
  var calendarSource = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('de.german#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com');
  var calendarDestination = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('4***************4@group.calendar.google.com');
  var start = new Date('2021', '0', '1');
  // Sometimes, years are not 365 days, so better spell it out
  var end = new Date('2021', '11', '31');
  var eventToCopy = calendarSource.getEvents(start, end);
  //var eventToCheck = calendarDestination.getEvents(start, end);   //check if already inserted
  var easterArr    = ['Karfreitag','Karwoche test1'];              //  0,0   0,1
  var christmasArr = ['Heiligabend','Weihnachtswoche'];             //  1,0   1,1
  var newYearArr   = ['Neujahrstag','Neujahrswoche'];               //  2,0   2,1
  var holidayArray = [easterArr, christmasArr, newYearArr];
  var copyHoliday;
  for (var i in eventToCopy) {
    if (eventToCopy[i].getTitle() == holidayArray[0][0]) {
      {
        var eventWeekDay = eventToCopy[i].getAllDayStartDate().getDay();    //get weekday to calculate circumfering week
        var toMonday = eventWeekDay - 1;
        var toSunday = 7 - eventWeekDay;
        var startDate = eventToCopy[i].getAllDayStartDate();
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - toMonday)
        var endDate = eventToCopy[i].getAllDayEndDate();
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + toSunday);
        var eventToCheck = calendarDestination.getEvents(startDate, endDate);   //get all events in this period
        if ( eventToCheck.length == 0 ) {
            copyHoliday = true;
          }
        for (var j = 0;  eventToCheck.length > 0; j++) {
          if ( eventToCheck[j].getTitle() !== holidayArray[0][1] ) {
            copyHoliday = true;
          }
          else { break; }
        }
        if (copyHoliday == true) {
          calendarDestination.createAllDayEvent(holidayArray[0][1], startDate, endDate);
        }
        return;
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

Of course the next step is to expand the FOR loop so the code goes automatically through the array,I just want to fix this issue first.

Thanks for Your valuable help!

Comment: Can you share more details on the issue? Do you get any error? Can you point out the changes you made?

Comment: Added screenshots and explanation.

Comment: updated content: I have fixed the issue with the array myself now, but  a new issue arose if any existing events need to be evaluated.

Comment: Please create a new post with the new issue you are having. This should be one question per post, and if you have found the answer to your original question, you should have added it as the answer to the post so more people can be helped.